# Inconsistent Line Endings Error

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I wrote a software for auto-generating some lines of code. However when I do a copy and paste of that code in a class after reopening it again I confront an Inconsistent Line Ending Erros.
How is that so? Where the problem lies and how can I fix it? it is about carriege return and line feeds.!
Sample of that class:

```
          txtResult.Text += "  End Get" + CrLf
      txtResult.Text += "  Set(ByVal Value As " + GeneratePropertyCast(para.DbType) + ")" + CrLf
      txtResult.Text += "    Item("
      txtResult.Text += GeneratePropertyColumn(para.ParameterName) + ")= Value" + CrLf
      txtResult.Text += "  End Set" + CrLf
      txtResult.Text += "End Property" + CrLf
```

Comment: It would be easier to try and answer with some sample code

Comment: @Floyd and how do you plan on spotting different line endings then?

Comment: @slhck: Not the generated 'code', but the one that generated it. And OP has done that now.

Comment: Please stop posting "AnyOne??" comments. It's been less than 30 minutes since you posted the question. You'll still get responses, as long as you're patient. Those comments come across as rude, and make you *less* likely to get help.

Comment: Ok Cody. Yes sorry I am a bit exhausted!

Answer (score 4):

I'm a little unclear on exactly where the issue is, but it looks like you're building VB.Net code in C#, and that you're getting the inconsistent line ending errors for that code in VB.

Ok, so some ideas to try that might help:

1. Don't use `CrLf` - that's a backwards compatibility thing. Use `Environment.NewLine`
2. Your example is not a complete block of compilable code, your errant alternate new line chars could be from another part of your code.
3. Visual Studio usually auto-fixes inconsistent line endings, for instance if you past a snippet from the web. What are you pasting the code from and into?
4. Don't use lots of `+=` with strings, use a `StringBuilder` instance instead. You can also use a `TextWriter` or `StreamWriter` which includes a `WriteLine` method.
5. Or, even better, .Net has a load of [CodeDom stuff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) that lets you build up code by specifying what you want rather than the raw code.

Comment: WHy Not using them? Can u explain those as well Keith?

Comment: I wouldn't use a `StringBuilder` here, either. `String.Concat` or `String.Format` is a *much* better option. `StringBuilder` really only makes sense in a loop, which isn't the case in the sample code we're shown.

Comment: @Bahman - why not use what? `CrLf` is platform dependent (it's only there to make upgrading from VB6 easier), `Environment.NewLine` is not. `+=` is slow for large strings with lots of operations, `StringBuilder` is optimised for building up large strings.

Comment: @Cody Gray - I'd agree, but I don't know the context and all of them are better than `+=` for strings.

Comment: So What i am saying is that should not be the cause of inconsistent line ENDING! Maybe the CrL, but what the rest has to do with line endings?

Comment: @Bahman - yeah, I did get that :-S Points 1, 2, 3 refer specifically to things you could do or places to check. Point 3 had a question that could help us answer your question if you replied. Points 4 and 5 refer to alternate ways of building the code that don't have to worry about the inconsistency.

Comment: I checked them all, Still having that erro while I did them all!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where you actually get the error (when opening the code posted above, or when opening the code generated by the code above), I would suggest you to open your files with a hex editor and check if all the line endings fit "0D 0A".
 If you are working with any other platform then windows (linux, mac) the line endings you need are different.
Take a look [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations) to ensure your using the right endings.

Comment: Alex, i'm getting it when I am opening this class!